# Suppose that for any two sets B and C in X , B ⊆ C or C ⊆ B. Prove that there is a set A ∈ X such that A ⊆ B for all B ∈ X.

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a nonempty finite collection of sets. Suppose that for any two sets B and C in X , B ⊆ C or C ⊆ B. Prove that there is a set A ∈ X such that A ⊆ B for all B ∈ X.

I was able to start the proof by induction. For the base case, when X is a collection of sets with only 1 set, by the given property (B ⊆ C or C ⊆ B), any 2 sets in X must be equal. Thus P(n) is true.
For P(n+1): I let X be a set with n+1 elements and suppose that for any 2 sets B and C in X, B ⊆ C or C ⊆ B. I let L∈X and those subsets that don't contain L are those subsets of X-{L}.

After this is where I'm stuck. How do I show that there is a set A∈X such that A is a subset of B, for all B∈X?

Comment: Induction's the right idea. Suppose you've got $n+1$ sets. Pick one, call it $D$, and hide it. The other $n$ sets satisfy the induction hypothesis, so among them there's a set $A$ with the required property. Now think about $A$ and $D$.

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten pretty far!  Notice that $X' = X-\{L\}$ is a collection of $n$ sets, and still has the property that for any $B, C \in X'$, $B \subseteq C$ or $C \subseteq B$.  So by the inductive hypothesis, there exists an $A' \in X'$ such that $A' \subseteq B$ for all $B \in X'$.  Can you finish?